# How do I access an element inside a v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to create a group of temporary inputs that are saved only when I click a button. The inputs are created in rows using a `v-for` loop, with each row containing a **SAVE** button. How do I get the values of the inputs from within the **SAVE** button's click handler?

*Script excerpt:*

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      listCollection: [
        {
          name:'example',
          phone:'+73849869485',
          email:'anything@example.com',
          address:'something',
          disabled: true,
        },
        {
          name:'example',
          phone:'+73849869485',
          email:'anything@example.com',
          address:'something',
          disabled: true,
        },
        {
          name:'example',
          phone:'+73849869485',
          email:'anything@example.com',
          address:'something',
          disabled: true,
        },
        {
          name:'example',
          phone:'+73849869485',
          email:'anything@example.com',
          address:'something',
          disabled: true,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    modifyList(index) {
      if (this.listCollection[index].disabled === false) {
        this.listCollection[index].name = index; // <-- change it to input field's value here, not to index
        this.listCollection[index].phone = index;
        this.listCollection[index].email = index;
        this.listCollection[index].address = index;
        this.listCollection[index].disabled = true;
      }
    },
  }
}
```

*Template excerpt:*

```
<tr v-for="(t,index) in listCollection">
  <td><input type="text" :value="t.name"  class="form-control" :class="index" placeholder="name" :disabled="t.disabled" ></td>
  <td><input type="text" :value="t.phone"  class="form-control" :class="index" placeholder="phone" :disabled="t.disabled" ></td>
  <td><input type="text" :value="t.email"  class="form-control" :class="index" placeholder="email" :disabled="t.disabled" ></td>
  <td><input type="text" :value="t.address"  class="form-control" :class="index" placeholder="address" :disabled="t.disabled" ></td>
  <div class="px-2">
    <img class="icon" v-b-tooltip.hover.bottom="'edit'" v-on:click="t.disabled = !t.disabled" src="../../node_modules/open-iconic/svg/action-redo.svg" alt="icon name">
    <img class="icon" v-b-tooltip.hover.bottom="'delete'" v-on:click="deleteList(index)" src="../../node_modules/open-iconic/svg/delete.svg" alt="icon name">
    <img class="icon" v-b-tooltip.hover.bottom="'save'" v-on:click="modifyList(index)" src="../../node_modules/open-iconic/svg/cloud-upload.svg" alt="icon name">
  </div>
</tr>
```

If I use `v-model` (e.g., `v-model="t.name"`) instead of `:value`, I can't access it in `modifyList()`, but If I use `v-model="something"` for example, my table doesn't get filled in with values from the array.

Comment: The `v-for` should have a `:key` then using this `:key` you will access/edit the data

Comment: friendly advice ... try to make your questions shorter, you will very likely get more help that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to access the inputs in your handler, you could use a temporary variable in each array element to automatically store the corresponding input value, and then copy them over when you're ready to save in `modifyList()`:

1. Define `saveTemp()` to save the user's input in a temporary variable (e.g., `__temp`) within the current array element (`item`):

   ```
   saveTemp(item, key, value) {
     item.__temp = item.__temp || {};
     item.__temp[key] = value;
   }
   ```
2. Add `<input>` [`change`-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) handlers that call `saveTemp()` to store the input value in the current array element (`t`):

   ```
   <td><input @change="saveTemp(t, 'name', $event.target.value)" :value="t.name"></td>
   <td><input @change="saveTemp(t, 'phone', $event.target.value)" :value="t.phone"></td>
   <td><input @change="saveTemp(t, 'email', $event.target.value)" :value="t.email"></td>
   <td><input @change="saveTemp(t, 'address', $event.target.value)" :value="t.address"></td>
   ```
3. Update the **SAVE** button's `click`-handler to pass the array element (`t`) instead of `index` to `modifyList()`:

   ```
   <img v-b-tooltip.hover.bottom="'save'" v-on:click="modifyList(t)">
   ```
4. Update `modifyList()` to check for `__temp` data to be committed, using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

   ```
   modifyList(item) {
     if (!item.disabled && item.__temp) {
       Object.assign(item, item.__temp);
       delete item.__temp;
     }
   },
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/047p17p64p)

Comment: Really nice solution! Thanks for the answer, accepted it!

Comment: @ewool No problem :)